# MSI installation interrupted by custom action DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, windows-installer, orca

I have used a Visual Studio setup project to create an MSI. I have edited the MSI in Orca so that a custom action is performed via a DLL when it is first opened. When I run the MSI, `msiexec` logs the following:

```
MSI (c) (E4:BC) [15:28:14:453]: Doing action: CustomAction1
Action 15:28:14: CustomAction1. 
Action start 15:28:14: CustomAction1.
MSI (c) (E4:BC) [15:28:14:453]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'CustomAction1' 
MSI (c) (E4:BC) [15:28:14:453]: Creating MSIHANDLE (13) of type 790542 for thread 3260
MSI (c) (E4:B4) [15:28:14:453]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\DOCUME~1\USERNA~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\MSIA3.tmp, Entrypoint: SampleFunction
MSI (c) (E4:B4) [15:28:14:453]: Closing MSIHANDLE (13) of type 790542 for thread 3260
Action ended 15:28:14: CustomAction1. Return value 3.
MSI (c) (E4:BC) [15:28:14:468]: Doing action: FatalErrorForm
Action 15:28:14: FatalErrorForm. 
Action start 15:28:14: FatalErrorForm.
MSI (c) (E4:BC) [15:28:14:468]: Note: 1: 2235 2:  3: ExtendedType 4: SELECT `Action`,`Type`,`Source`,`Target`, NULL, `ExtendedType` FROM `CustomAction` WHERE `Action` = 'FatalErrorForm'
```

The installer wizard then displays the error message: `The installer was interrupted before MyProduct could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again.`

The custom DLL is written in C++. Here is the source code:

MyCustomAction.cpp:

```
// MyCustomAction.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "stdafx.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return TRUE;
}

UINT __stdcall SampleFunction(MSIHANDLE hModule)
{
        //This is the function that is called by the MSI
        //It is empty because I just want to check that it can be called without interrupting the installer, then I will add the actual functionality
}
```

MyCustomAction.def:

```
; MyCustomAction.def
;
; defines the exported functions which will be available to the MSI engine

LIBRARY      "MyCustomAction" 
DESCRIPTION  'Custom Action DLL'

EXPORTS
    SampleFunction
```

I have also referenced `msi.lib` in the DLL's additional dependencies. Why does the custom action interrupt the installation when I am currently not explicitly telling it do anything? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

In Orca, the custom action is in the `Binary` table and is type 1 in the `CustomAction` table. The custom action is `Immediate` and takes place after `IsolateComponents` and before `WelcomeForm` in the `InstallUISequence` table.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything; doesn't VS generate a warning?

Comment: @tkausl No warnings. It builds successfully.

Comment: Then the warnings-level isn't high enough I guess. Still, the function needs to return something.

Comment: @tkausl I've also made it `return 1;`, but I got the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, because MSI wants `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @tkausl I've tried returning `1`, `ERROR_SUCCESS` and `MsiCloseHandle(hModule)`. No luck with any.

Comment: You need to add more information. Is the custom action deferred or immediate? Is the Dll in the Binary table? Exactly what type is it, and where is it sequenced in the MSI?

Comment: @PhilDW More info added.

Comment: Can we ask what the custom action is for? In many cases there are better ways to achieve what you want using built-in MSI mechanism or custom support available in WiX - which incidentally is a much better toolkit for advanced Windows Installer setups than Visual Studio setups will ever be. Do add a message box in that custom action to see if it actually runs.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code and your post to indicate that you are actually returning ERROR_SUCCESS. Whether it fixes the issue or not, the point is that it is the correct thing to do. If it doesn't return a value the call sequence will fail and get an error.

Your Dll is probably not loading because of missing dependencies. If you put a simple messagebox call in your code you'll at least see if the code is actually starting to run. C++ will require runtime support Dlls that may not be on the system already.

If it turns out that you have dependencies on C++ runtimes then you'll need to install them before running your MSI. That's what the prerequisites choice is for - it generates a setup.exe to install the dependencies and then installs your MSI.

Comment: I suppose he could try **static linking** to prevent any dependency problems - I think a setup dll is one of the few types of binaries that actually should be minimum dependency in all cases (in most other cases I think static linking is wrong). Overall I think he should go for WiX instead for something this advanced? The bigger question is what the custom action is for.

Comment: Just checked Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition (home PC). I can see an option to statically link MFC in the project's property pages, but I thought there was one for static linking altogether (for standard libraries too). I haven't used this feature in years so I am not sure, and perhaps the community edition doesn't allow proper static linking? Phil, would you mind checking this information (webJose's answer): 
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/18397/ ("the manifest must go" makes me a bit concerned, but I want MFC, ATL, CRT all statically linked or better yet avoided for a CA dll).

Comment: Doesn't seem to me that the manifest comment is relevant - just use the static linking to embed the runtime Dlls, or run the VC_runtime prerequisite first.